# How to change from one feature branch to another?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I am working on branch `A` cut from `featA`. So I was keeping `A` uptodate with `featA`. But there is another branch `featB` newly created and has slightly different commits than `featA`. Now I wanted to make my branch `A` uptodate with `featB` without `featA` changes. How can I resolve this considering I may get merge conflicts? Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Better draw a sample commit graph to show what you want to be included and not included as your desire result.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
git checkout A
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/featB
```

Comment: my gitbash went to rebase mode and asking to pick each commit.

Comment: Is there any merge conflicts??

Comment: yes there was 1 merge conflict and I have resolved it and I added a commit

Comment: It works now as expected??

Comment: same issue now also, After the merge conflict is resolved it is asking me to manually pick each commit

Comment: @happytohelp what do you mean by "asking me to manually pick each commit"? I don't recall rebase will work like this.  I suspect you may not be familiar with resolving conflicts in git rebase?

Comment: @Adrian, your assumption is correct.

Comment: @happytohelp I will strongly suggest you to go thru some tutorials and make sure you understand how to perform rebase and merge with conflict resolvation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this,

```sh
git checkout A
git pull origin featA # pull update from `featA`
git pull origin featB # pull update from `featB`
```

Now branch `A` has all commits of `featA` and `featB`

Comment: this is not what I needed. I do not want featA changes and only wanted featB changes

Comment: then you can only pull from featB by git pull origin featB

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on your commit graph and what you want to include or not

Assuming you have

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- e   <<- featA
     ^         ^
      \         \- f    <<- A
       \- g             <<- featB
```

If it is what you want:

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- e   <<- featA
     ^
      \
       \- g             <<- featB
          ^
           \- f'        <<- A
```

You can simply do a

```
git rebase  --onto featB featA A
```

If you want you `A` to include `a,b,c,d,f,g`, you should do

```
git checkout A  # make sure you are at A
git merge featB
```

which will give you

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- e         <<- featA
     ^         ^
      \         \- f <- h     <<- A
       \               /        
        \-g <---------/       <<- featB
```